# Calabash - No launchable activity found in Android Manifest

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

When I run `calabash-android console app-release.apk` I am getting this error message.

```
C:\Users\mihirj\Desktop\MOTO\Testing>calabash-android console app-release.apk
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.15/lib/calabash-andr
oid/helpers.rb:50:in `rescue in main_activity': No launchable activity found in
AndroidManifest (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.15/lib/
calabash-android/helpers.rb:25:in `main_activity'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.15/bin/
calabash-android-console.rb:20:in `calabash_console'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.15/bin/
calabash-android:96:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you add more details like Cucumber version, ruby version, calabash version etc?

Comment: Try console for another application. If it works then there may be an issue in your app.  Here is an sample app: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android-demoapp

Comment: Its not working for any app

Comment: What version of calabash-android you're using?

Comment: @Aravin ruby - 2.2.3 , cucumber - 2.1.0, calabash-android - 0.5.15

Comment: After reinstalling after again along with development toolkit , I get this error -  `Could not execute command to start test server (RuntimeError)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97543/discussion-between-aravin-and-mjosh).